# C++ illegal in base/member initializer list

Tags: c++

Возникает ошибка `illegal in base/member initializer list` при объявлении переменных в конструкторе. Либо я не понимаю как это работает.

.cpp

```
DroneConnection::DroneConnection( void )
    :SLEEP_BETWEEN_POLLS_MS (1000)
    :TIMEOUT (5)
{
    {

    m_port = 0;
    getDataFromXml();
    m_wasDataRecieved.store( false );
    m_continueRecieving.store( false );
    }
}
```

.h

```
...
private:

    const int SLEEP_BETWEEN_POLLS_MS;
    const int TIMEOUT;
    const int TIMEOUT_MS;
...
```

Компилятор показывает так же примичание `expected {'` на `:TIMEOUT (5)`

P.S. Не кидайтесь тапками.. все еще в изучении и понятии языка...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Здесь нужна запятая вместо двоеточия. Двоеточие отделяет список инициализации от имени конструктора. Элементы списка разделяются запятыми.

```
DroneConnection::DroneConnection( void )
    :SLEEP_BETWEEN_POLLS_MS (1000),
    TIMEOUT (5) {...}
```